# Does the standard .NET library depend on any unmanaged DLL-s?

Tags: .net

Just out of curiosity, does the .NET framework itself depend on any unmanaged DLL-s when accessing the standard library ? For example i call method A and -under the hood- that method A or any other method inside that method A executes a PInvoke against an unmanaged DLL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the .Net libraries use unmanaged functions a lot. There are two types of unmanaged functions (that I know) the library can call: either methods from the Framework itself, or methods from some other DLL (using PInvoke).

The methods that are implemented in the framework are marked with [`[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimplattribute.aspx). Those that come from other unmanaged DLLs are marked with [`[DllImport]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx).

In my version of mscorlib.dll alone, there is 7241 methods that are implemented internally by the framework (e.g. the getter of `string.Length`) and 535 that are from some unmanaged DLL (many of them are in the internal class `Win32Native`).

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course, the framework contains innumerable calls to the underlying Windows API.
Look at the decompiled code of File.Move:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
public static void Move(string sourceFileName, string destFileName)
{
    if (sourceFileName == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("sourceFileName", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentNull_FileName"));
    }
    if (destFileName == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("destFileName", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentNull_FileName"));
    }
    if (sourceFileName.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_EmptyFileName"), "sourceFileName");
    }
    if (destFileName.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_EmptyFileName"), "destFileName");
    }
    string fullPathInternal = Path.GetFullPathInternal(sourceFileName);
    new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write | FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, new string[] { fullPathInternal }, false, false).Demand();
    string dst = Path.GetFullPathInternal(destFileName);
    new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, new string[] { dst }, false, false).Demand();
    if (!InternalExists(fullPathInternal))
    {
        __Error.WinIOError(2, fullPathInternal);
    }
    if (!Win32Native.MoveFile(fullPathInternal, dst))
    {
        __Error.WinIOError();
    }
}
```

As you can see, at the end of the game we have a call to Win32Native.MoveFile.
which is defined as...

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
internal static extern bool MoveFile(string src, string dst);
```

Answer (score 0):

The framework class library uses a lot of P/Invokes against different Windows API DLLs. For example, see the internal class Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native in mscorlib which contains many DllImports. For example, System.IO.FileStream.Read ultimately uses Win32.ReadFile.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions enum, it has a Unmanaged flag. Cant really find where it is used though.

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
  [Flags]
  [ComVisible(true)]
  [Serializable]
  public enum MethodImplOptions
  {
    Unmanaged = 4,
    ForwardRef = 16,
    PreserveSig = 128,
    InternalCall = 4096,
    Synchronized = 32,
    NoInlining = 8,
    NoOptimization = 64,
  }
}
```