# Does RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes write a sequential stream of bits to the byte[] result

Tags: c#, random

I've been trying to figure out the implementation of RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes to answer the title question.

To rephrase,  does the GetBytes method generate a stream/array of bits, and then just sequentially write them to the byte array, such that I could recreate the original stream/array by looping over the bytes in order and looking at the bits in each byte?

I checked the source as found here: [rngcryptoserviceprovider.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rngcryptoserviceprovider.cs), but it calls [out to the CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491337/what-is-dllimportqcall) apparently, and I don't know how to get the source for that.

```
    [DllImport(JitHelpers.QCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
    private static extern void GetBytes(SafeProvHandle hProv, byte[] randomBytes, int count);
```

Comment: Out of interest, why does it matter to you?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "recreate"? There are no streams involved here.

Comment: True, the docs talk about a sequence of (byte) values.

Comment: I'd like a list/stream/array of random bits.   GetBytes returns bytes.  I want to know if GetBytes simply returns a list of bits stored in bytes.

Comment: Ideally I'd like a hardware RNG source, such that each bit could theoretically be mapped to one "physical" event, (rather than from a seeded PRNG algorithm). Since I currently don't have such a device, I was looking into the details of .Net's RNG source.

Comment: If the bytes are random and evenly distributed, each bit should also be random and evenly distributed.. does it matter how they were generated?

Comment: @Blorgbeard, it may not matter.  I'm attempting to recreate an old statistics experiment which originally used a hardware source, generating sequential bits.   I simply don't know enough about statistics to know if a different type of random source will introduce unknown bias.  In theory, you're right.  In practice,  I know statistics can have very subtle, unintuitive catches

Comment: @Kal_Torak you could use [random.org](http://random.org)?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments for more information, I **think** I know what you're asking...

So actually, you should use the RNGCryptoServiceProvider's `GetNonZeroBytes(byte[] data)` method. This will prevent you from receiving 8 zero bits in a row, which would throw off your statistical methods. Then, as blorgbeard-is-out has pointed out, "The bytes are random and evenly distributed, each bit should also be random and evenly distributed."

Also, the RNGCryptoServiceProvider can be slightly tricky to use, so I have provided a short example, along with how to convert the byte array into bits:

```
/* A static member inside a class somewhere. Only instantiate this once per execution of your application. */
static RNGCryptoServiceProvider _rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

/* Inside a method */
byte[] rngBytes4 = new byte[4];
 _rng.GetNonZeroBytes(rngBytes4); // This populates the byte array

BitArray randomBits = new BitArray(rngBytes4);
foreach(bool bit in randomBits)
{
    // Do something with bit here
}

// And, because its not obvious how to get BitArray to return you a list: 
List<bool> randomBitsAsList = randomBits.Cast<bool>().ToList();
```